# pagination problem default page url with search query

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to make pagination but i want it to be used when anything is searched or not
hence how can set the href such that when a query is there then the next page link goes to

```
href="/c?search=sample&page=<%= i %>"
```

and when there is no query then it goes to

```
href="/c?page=<%= i %>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand your question well, in which part of the application do you have the href? you can inline javascript in html

```
search ? href="/c?search=sample&page=<%= i %>" : href="/c?page=<%= i %>"
```

Comment: i have the search query in different router file

Comment: When I run a search with constraints and get more than the set paginate amount, if I change the pages the search query is lost and my default page 2 is shown rather than the 2nd page of results